# Save a picture in Tiff format without compression

Tags: c#, vb.net, screenshot, tiff

I just found out TIFF has several formats. For some reason when using

```
Using bm As New Bitmap(rect.Width, rect.Width)
bm.Save("C:\testfolder\screenshot.png", Imaging.ImageFormat.Tiff)
```

the format becomes LZW compressed, which I can't use in a third-party library.

After some searching I found that .NET does provide a library to save as TIFF with different compression options, I wanted to try them all but I don't know how to implement it. Or I should say I didn't figure out how to use it:

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.imaging.tiffcompressoption?view=netframework-4.8#examples

The purpose is I want to get a region screenshot and save it as TIFF.

```
Dim stream As New FileStream("new.tif", FileMode.Create)
Dim encoder As New TiffBitmapEncoder()
encoder.Compression = TiffCompressOption.Zip
encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(image))   <--what is this "image"?
encoder.Save(stream)
```

What is that `image` entity? A stream? How to get a region of captured screenshot to be saved as a TIFF?

If

```
Using bm As New Bitmap(rect.Width, rect.Width)
```

I don't mind to save it first then only reread the bmp stream. The only problem is I have no idea what is that "image" given in the example stands for.

I read some info from here but I still haven't figured it out:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapframe.create?view=netframework-4.8

Kindly offer me an example how to use the code if you figured it out.

Comment: bm above is System.Drawing.Bitmap while the "image" is System.Windows.Media.Imaging.WriteableBitMap I have no idea how to implement it

Comment: For the record most members under the `System.Windows` namespace (apart from `System.Windows.Forms`) is part of WPF (a different GUI framework) and not usually used in WinForms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can go the older System.Drawing way instead of System.Windows.Media way.

Adapted only slightly from the documentation for the [Encoder.Compression Field](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.imaging.encoder.compression?view=netframework-4.8):

```
Imports System.Drawing.Imaging
'' .....

Private Shared Function GetEncoderInfo(ByVal mimeType As String) As ImageCodecInfo
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim encoders() As ImageCodecInfo
    encoders = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders()

    j = 0
    While j < encoders.Length
        If encoders(j).MimeType = mimeType Then
            Return encoders(j)
        End If
        j += 1
    End While
    Return Nothing

End Function

Sub SaveAsTiff()
    Dim sampleFile = "C:\temp\ToTiff.png"

    Using bmp = Image.FromFile(sampleFile)
        Dim myImageCodecInfo = GetEncoderInfo("image/tiff")

        Dim myEncoder As Imaging.Encoder = Imaging.Encoder.Compression
        Dim myEncoderParameters = New EncoderParameters(1)
        Dim myEncoderParameter = New EncoderParameter(myEncoder, EncoderValue.CompressionNone)
        myEncoderParameters.Param(0) = myEncoderParameter

        bmp.Save("C:\temp\ToTiff.tif", myImageCodecInfo, myEncoderParameters)

    End Using

End Sub
```

However, it does not allow for ZIP compression. But that may not matter to you: [Which TIFF image compression is better, LZW or ZIP?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/10906/which-tiff-image-compression-is-better-lzw-or-zip)

Also, for screenshots, you might want to consider using the PNG format, especially if the images will be used on the web.

Comment: The quality of "New EncoderParameters(1)" is too low. I wanted Tiff because the library that I used specified only Tiff image only, that's why. This don't solve my problem yet but good try

Comment: @EricSia The `1` is nothing to do with quality - it is the number of parameters which it will hold. The example I showed is uncompressed, i.e. lossless. LZW and ZIP compression are also lossless.

Comment: I see. Butt the Tiff save using this method compressed with LZW by default is not acceptable by the third party library that I wanted to use unfortunately.

Comment: @EricSia That code is not using LZW compression. As specified by the `EncoderValue.CompressionNone`, it is not using compression. I would be surprised if a third-party library did not accept uncompressed TIFFs.

Comment: edit: yes my bad, I checked the old file that I tried just now. I think your reply solved my problem. Thanks buddy, I give it a few more try